# How access a downloaded library that is not showing up?

Tags: python, data-science

As a newbie, I am sorry if I posted wrong somehow.

I am new programming getting into data science, and recently tried to download scikit learn using the Anaconda distribution. The problem is whenever I tried to check by using **import sklearn**  or other methods it gives me an error. When I check the Anaconda Navigator it tells me it's installed.

How do I fix the problem?

Edit this is what happened:

```
    import sklearn

    Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
        import sklearn
    ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the error you are getting

Comment: ^ Post the error traceback message you are getting, we can only guess what the issue is without it.